# wpf datagrid.How to Merge or group cells..?

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I am  trying to Merge cells in WPF toolkit datagrid .I am trying to do something as shown in the image below.We can do this in Winforms datagrid.But how to do this using WPF toolkit datagrid ?.Or is there any alternative controls..?

Can we do this using listview or listbox..? 
Or is there any free controls available which have this functionality ?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490861/datagrid-merge-combine-rows-cells-and-columns/24505398#24505398

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datagrid, Merge/Combine rows, cells and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490861/datagrid-merge-combine-rows-cells-and-columns)