# Cell Merge in Datagrid in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to implement cell merge like functionality in a datagrid in silverlight. I have some rows which display a single value and some rows return all the values for all columns.So How to implement something like colspan for a particular row in datagrid ?

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282539/wpf-datagrid-how-to-merge-or-group-cells

Comment: Thanks Hasan I had seen it but that does not solve my purpose.Its kind of different from my problem

Comment: Please help guys its really important and urgent for me.

Comment: I want to implement cell merge like functionality using silverlight toolkit datagrid as it is shown in the attached image.

http://demo.digi-corp.com/cellmerge.jpg

Any help would be appreciated