# Merging DataGrid Cells (Row Wise & Column Wise)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

This question might have beebn asked earlier but i have not found ne solution....

How can i merge Two(or More) Cells in WPF DataGrid...

I have found no in built provision to do it, also i doint even know how to start

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282539/wpf-datagrid-how-to-merge-or-group-cells) `link shows some light but still no luck...`

What i wish to do is i need to Merge Two Cells of a Particula DataGridRow/DataGridColumn based on some value (It can be ne thing) Just like we Do in `Excel` (merging cells)

Comment: @all is is possible or ne alternatives if possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing cell templates for that cell in the row?  If you want the same pattern repeated, that's an idea.  You can use stack panels to align things as you need them.