# Datagrid, Merge/Combine rows, cells and columns

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I'm trying to acomplish exactly what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282539/wpf-datagrid-how-to-merge-or-group-cells) question is requesting, but unfortunately the code sample that was provided as the answer is gone, and I'm also not using WPF Toolkit, here the question that he did:

> I am trying to Merge cells in WPF toolkit datagrid .I am trying to do something as shown in the image below.We can do this in Winforms datagrid.But how to do this using WPF toolkit datagrid ?.Or is there any alternative controls..?
>
> Can we do this using listview or listbox..? Or is there any free
>   controls available which have this functionality ?

[image]

I found several answers that manage to do this with the DataGridView control, but I do not want to use Form objects in a WPF project, is there a way to acomplish this?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3xzotz i have implemented this using listbox.i will add code if  you need this

Comment: Would be glad if you could share it, might be able to get my head around it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Recource**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="customBlue"  A="255"   R="54" G="95" B="177"  />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="customBlueBrush" Color="{StaticResource customBlue}"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="customBlueBrushOpacity" Color="LightGray" Opacity="0.11"></SolidColorBrush>
    <Style x:Key="calcyListbox"  TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="35"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="30"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Manufacturer" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Name" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark" Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="CPU" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="2"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="RAM" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="3"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Price" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe Ui Dark"  Foreground="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="4"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="noStyleToListboxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

**xaml**

```
<ListBox  MaxHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ManufacturerList}" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}"  x:Name="ManufacturerListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Style="{StaticResource calcyListbox}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource noStyleToListboxItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" ></Border>
                <ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="0"></Border>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="1"></Border>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="-2" Grid.Column="2"></Border>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CPU}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ram}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding price}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="3"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**c#**

```
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Manufacturer> ManufacturerList = new List<Manufacturer>();

        ManufacturerList.Add(new Manufacturer()
        {
            Company = "DEll",
            Models = new List<Model>(){new Model(){CPU = "T7250", Name = "Inspiron1525", price =234434 , Ram= "2048 MB" },
                                       new Model(){CPU = "T5750", Name = "Studio 1535", price =234443 , Ram= "2048 MB" },
                                       new Model(){CPU = "T5780", Name = "Vastro 1510", price =234434 , Ram= "2048 MB" },}
        });

        ManufacturerList.Add(new Manufacturer()
        {
            Company = "Lenovo",
            Models = new List<Model>(){new Model(){CPU = "T1230", Name = "l123", price =23546454 , Ram= "1024 MB" },
                                      new Model(){CPU = "T1230", Name = "l1423", price =2346456 , Ram= "1024 MB" },
                                      new Model(){CPU = "T1230", Name = "ldf123", price =2344646 , Ram= "1024 MB" },}
        });

        ManufacturerListBox.ItemsSource = ManufacturerList;
```

---

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ram { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string CPU { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me, I didn't manage to implement this into a Datagrid, but I'll use this to create a CustomControl with the ListBox and Buttons to recreate a Datagrid. Thanks for this great sample!

Comment: I m glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

For a merged cell, bind its `Margin` and set it to a negative value equal to the sum width/height of the associated merged cells - then the cell will spill across and on top the neighboring cells.

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell"> 
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{{Binding BorderThickness[5], Mode=OneWay}}"/> 
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{{Binding CellMargins[5], Mode=OneWay}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Block.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>             
    </Style>
```

The bindings are indexed because `CellMargins` is an `ObservableCollection` of `Thickness`. The viewmodel is row-level, so each column binds to a different index.

Before this gets downvoted, let me say this can lead to some undesirable visual quirks. Getting this to work perfectly requires a bit of code-behind, such as:

The cell margins' negative values need to be updated whenever a column width changes, so I handled the datagrid's `LayoutUpdated` event, where I iterated through the columns, measured their current `ActualWidths` and updated the margins accordingly. I likewise update the `BorderThickness` to show/hide cell borders as needed. Disabling the selection highlight for cells that are "hidden" is another trick.

Note this means keeping track of what cells (i.e., which row viewmodels and column indices) you want merged separately in code-behind.

This method is complicated and probably not the easiest for every situation, but I found it useful for my purposes. I needed a `Datagrid` where the user could merge/unmerge cells and create/delete columns, similar to Excel. Furthermore, I wanted to stick with `DataGridTextColumns` (instead of custom `TemplateColums`) because of their built-in functionality (recognized keyboard edit commands, copy/paste, etc.)