# Dynamic Property Value Binding in the ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a listbox "lbModernLineView" in which it is bound to "Lines" observable collection and each listbox item is bound with "Line" object. I have another listbox within this listbox named"InnerListBox".

I am going to show a pop up to the user once the user right click on the "InnerListBox" .In this pop up I am going to show all the properties in the "Line" class(for eg: Value1,Value2 etc).

if a user selects a "property" name from  the popup, I need to show that property "value" into the InnerListBox. (for eg: if a user selects "value1" ,then the correspoding value in that "Line " objects need to display in the InnerListBox).

User can select upto 5 property names from the Poppup and that five property values and five property names for that "Line" object should should display in the "InnerListBox".

How can I bind these dynamic property values in a listbox item?

```
public class Line
{
 public int Value1{ get; set; }
 public int Value2{ get; set; }
 public int Value3{ get; set; }
 public int Value4{ get; set; }
 public int Value5{ get; set; }
 public int Value6{ get; set; }
 public int Value7{ get; set; }
 public int Value8{ get; set; }
}
```

Following are the part of my  listBox sample

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbModernLineView"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Margin="2,2,2,2"
                 FontFamily="Courier New"
                 FontSize="13"   ItemsSource="{Binding Lines,IsAsync=True,
                                       Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,1,2,1">
                        <Border.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding desription}" />
                        </Border.ToolTip>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="89" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Border Grid.Column="1"
                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,2,0" >
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ModernColumn,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="InnerListBox" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Background="Transparent" >
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"> </ColumnDefinition>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Prop}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent"/>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                                </ListBox>
<
</ListBox>
```

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490861/datagrid-merge-combine-rows-cells-and-columns.

Comment: Hi Heena,That is not my requiremnt. your example shows normal binding.But I need it to by dyanmic ,means if I select a property name from the pop up,then that property value should display into the innerlistbox

Comment: Hi @RoshilK - Have you solved this problem, or are you still working on it?  Are you able to add properties to the Line class as part of the solution, if necessary?  Also, could you post an image of the selection form so we can visualize what you are trying to do?