# How can I create a WPF data grid with an enhanced table header?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm currently working on a WPF based data management system, which is planned to replace the old Excel based one. This old system is mainly consist of tables where the user can input his data. One of these tables looks like this:

[image: Example input table]

The number of rows and columns are fixed (25 rows per day, from 6AM to 6AM the next day).

It is kinda difficult to provide an input form for this kind of data, so I tried implementing the table in WPF using a DataGrid. However, I wasn't able to get these nifty merged cells, especially in the first and second row.

Are there any 'DataGrid' usercontrols on the market that allow merging cells, shading rows etc.? Or is there any other way of providing an user-friendly input form that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for Grid cell merging tool you can try `Devexpress`.

Here is a link on [how to merge DataGrid cells using Devexpress](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/thinking/archive/2014/11/17/wpf-grid-control-cell-merging-and-more-coming-soon-in-v14-2.aspx)

Another solution to merge DataGrid Rows is to use a [ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490861/datagrid-merge-combine-rows-cells-and-columns)

Comment: The ListBox solution is great! It gave me idea on how to make my input form even better.