# Merging cells in WPF DataGrid vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make a `DataGrid` in WPF, where some of the cells will "merge together", if they are alike.

Example:

```
+---------+------+-----+
| Country | Name | Age |
+---------+------+-----+
|         | Lisa | 24  |
+         +------+-----+
| Danmark |  Per | 32  |
+         +------+-----+
|         | Hans | 33  |
+---------+------+-----+
| Germany | Mick | 22  |
+---------+------+-----+
```

Is there any way to achieve this using `DataGrid` using binding?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Looks like that you need not to merging, but grouping data.

Comment: Google-fu! [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490861/datagrid-merge-combine-rows-cells-and-columns).

Comment: Yes, it is possible and it is very easy. I will post that after sometime.

Comment: @tym32167 Have been looking into this. Haven't found anything useful so far that would make that DataGrid look like they way I want it to.

Comment: @Kilazur "This" I've ready looked at. Nothing like what I'm trying to achieve. "that" will give me the result, but I was hoping there was an easier way I was missing. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @nickosv dont think that there are easy way to achieve that without grouping.

Comment: @tym32167 I just have a hard time finding something useful to help me get started. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: I made a [demo](https://github.com/Orace/SO/tree/main/SO_39748090) where I use a variation of the accepted answer. It uses nested `ListView` instead of `DataGrid` to improve UX in regards to selection behavior. Also the extra borders are removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trick to such scenarios is to use the `Groups` formed in `CollectionViewSource` as the `ItemsSource` of a `DataGrid`. And, use a `DataGrid` itself as the `CellTemplate` of `Column`.

***Xaml***

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CvsKey">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" Loaded="dg_Loaded" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HeadersVisibility="All" Grid.Column="0" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Country"  Width="75">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>                           
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"  Width="75">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>            
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`DataGrid.Loaded event`

```
 private void dg_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var groups = (this.Resources["CvsKey"] as CollectionViewSource).View.Groups;
        dg.ItemsSource = groups;
    }
```

This should get you started.

Output :

[image: Vertical Grid Output]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for answering, this is exactly what I was looking for.
I fail to see how I'm supposed to add objects to the binded ItemsSource, would you be so kind to explain?

Comment: @nickosv couldnt get you

Comment: Okay, uhm.. how do I add objects to the collection that's bound?

Comment: You shouldnt. Because grouping is done when you are done with your data. But still that is possible. Be more specific with ur requirement, will see to it.

Comment: How else am I going to display "Denmark", "Robert" etc. 
All I want to know, is how you "insert" the data to the collection that's shown in the DataGrid, I cannot figure it out myself :)

Comment: @nickosv i used Loaded event, and get the groups created by the CollectionViewSource. `var groups` variable contains list of Groups. This list is used as `ItemsSource` of main dgrid. Every group has Name property and Items property. See XAML for main DataGrid, also see the Bindings of Columns.

Comment: @nickosv if this solves your problem, request u to mark it as answer along  with an upvote.

Comment: I just can't seem to get data "into" the DataGrid from the binding.

Comment: Exactly as you wrote it, yes :-) But where/how am I supposed to enter the data for the Items that is bound to the DataGrid?

Comment: Click here http://pastebin.com/MxMn0WFy , you will get Window1.xaml, and window1.xaml.cs code

Comment: Perfect, that was what I needed :) Thanks a bunch for your answer and your patience

Comment: @nickosv Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

I have created a demo project on [github.com](https://github.com/praful-hunde/DataGridDemo)
     Output:

[image]

XAML Code: Grid with two columns and each containing a DataGrid

```c#
 <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid Name="basketNameDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
                      CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RowHeight}"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Basket">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <DataGrid Name="itemDataGrid" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" 
                      CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item Name">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode = OneWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price, Mode = OneWay}" CanUserSort="False"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

C# code - There are three classes to structure data.
(*Removed constructors to reduce code lines*)

```cs
  class Item
    { 
        public Name {get;}
        public Price {set;}
     }

    class Basket : List<Item>
     {  
        public Name {get;}
     }   

    class BasketCollection : List<Basket>
     {
     }
```

Code behind in MainWindow.cs - Populate data and assign to DataGrids.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //// Get some data to show in View
   var baskets = GetData();
   int rowHeight = 20; //// itemDataGrid row height is 20 in xaml

   //// Create a list of annonymous type with properties Name an RowHeight.
   //// RowHeight = Height of one row * number of items in current basket.
   var basketNameData = baskets.Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, RowHeight = rowHeight * x.Count });

   //// Assign data to first DataGrid 
   basketNameDataGrid.ItemsSource = basketNameData.ToList();

   //// Get list of  all Items in all baskets and assign as ItemsSource to second datagrid
   itemDataGrid.ItemsSource = baskets.SelectMany(basket => basket).ToList();
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets some data to bind to view
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Basket Collection</returns>
private BasketCollection GetData()
{
    var baskets = new BasketCollection();

    var fruitBasket = new Basket("Fruit");
    fruitBasket.Add(new Item("Alphonso Mango", 80));
    fruitBasket.Add(new Item("Nagpur Orange", 10));
    fruitBasket.Add(new Item("Dragon Fruit", 50));

    var vegetableBasket = new Basket("Vegetable");
    vegetableBasket.Add(new Item("Brinjal", 5));
    vegetableBasket.Add(new Item("Broccoli", 5));
    vegetableBasket.Add(new Item("Onion", 3)); 

    baskets.Add(fruitBasket);
    baskets.Add(vegetableBasket);

    return baskets;
}
```

**Note:** This solution do not actually  merge cells, but create such visual 
            effect.You may try this. Demo uses two DataGrid controls.
        The row height of first DataGrid is increased to create merged cell effect.

**Alternative :** [ReoGrid](https://reogrid.net/) is MS Excel compatible control which supports [merge/unmerge](https://reogrid.net/document/merge-and-unmerge/) cells feature like Excel. ReoGrid claims to be free and open source. It do not support Data Binding but it has [support for DataTable](https://reogrid.net/faq/fill-grid-with-datatable/).