# Merge cells in datagrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, merge, datagrid, cell

I have to create a datagrid control (not datagridview nor grid nor listview) that needs to merge some cells in case they have the same value (just some cells). 
All the data of the datagrid has to be fill with an ItemsSource binding and the structure of the datagrid will be defined programmatically not in the xaml, to make it generic for other classes.

In other posts like:

[Merging cells in WPF DataGrid vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748090/merging-cells-in-wpf-datagrid-vertically)

the definition of the structure (columns) of the table is defined in the xaml, but I need it to be generic with itemsource or something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? what would happen to the empty cell?

Comment: By merge I mean to put two cells in one cell. For example, if there are two cells in the same column with the same value, it has to be shown as one big cell with the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging cells in WPF DataGrid vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748090/merging-cells-in-wpf-datagrid-vertically)

Comment: Not duplicated, in that example that I looked before posting, the columns are defined ok the xaml, and as I say I need the xaml to be generic in order to use It repeteadly.

Answer (score 0):

DGV is definitely not like Excel in terms of merging 'cells', and I don't think there is a lot out there on this kind of thing, but you can try this approach.

```
private void MergeCellsInRow(int row, int col1, int col2)
{
    Graphics g = dataGridView1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(dataGridView1.GridColor);
    Rectangle r1 = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col1, row, true);
    Rectangle r2 = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col2, row, true);

    int recWidth = 0;
    string recValue = string.Empty;
    for (int i = col1; i <= col2; i++)
    {
    recWidth += dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(i, row, true).Width;
    if (dataGridView1[i, row].Value != null)
        recValue += dataGridView1[i, row].Value.ToString() + " ";
    }
    Rectangle newCell = new Rectangle(r1.X, r1.Y, recWidth, r1.Height);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor), newCell);
    g.DrawRectangle(p, newCell);
    g.DrawString(recValue, dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor), newCell.X + 3, newCell.Y + 3);
}

private void MergeCellsInColumn(int col, int row1, int row2)
{
    Graphics g = dataGridView1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(dataGridView1.GridColor);
    Rectangle r1 = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col, row1, true);
    Rectangle r2 = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col, row2, true);

    int recHeight = 0;
    string recValue = string.Empty;
    for (int i = row1; i <= row2; i++)
    {
    recHeight += dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(col, i, true).Height;
    if (dataGridView1[col, i].Value != null)
        recValue += dataGridView1[col, i].Value.ToString() + " ";
    }
    Rectangle newCell = new Rectangle(r1.X, r1.Y, r1.Width, recHeight);
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor), newCell);
    g.DrawRectangle(p, newCell);
    g.DrawString(recValue, dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor), newCell.X + 3, newCell.Y + 3);
}
```

Comment: It seems a good approach, the problem is that I have to use DataGrid, not DataGridView.