# Merging cells in column level by using DataGridCell.Margin property

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-columns, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have custom DataGridTemplateColumn. I'm trying to merge the column in RowSizeChangedEvent by setting the margin.
I have few rows and some of the rows will be duplicated. I would like to merge those rows in column level.
Each rows has Actual Height as 30. When i'm getting duplicate rows, i'm setting the margin for last duplicated row in negative value of top margin

For example

[image]
Actual Image

Expected

[image]

I have set currentcell margin for last duplicated row: (0,-(sum of duplicate row-Actual height of currentcell,0,0) in Row size changed event. It is working as expected at first time. 2nd time if i reloading that grid, it got failed. But margin size is as expected.
I have tried InvalidateVisual() and UpdateLayout() methods. Not useful.

Note: dynamically generating columns

Thanks!

Comment: Your example could be a solution if the cells were in one common container.
But if you expand the Dynamic Visual Tree, you will see that each cell is in its own branch of this tree.
And by setting the Margin (or any other property) you cannot move an item to another branch.

Comment: Check out a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748090/merging-cells-in-wpf-datagrid-vertically